# What is difference between mutex and semaphore in .Net?

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronous

What is difference between Mutex and Semaphore construct in .Net?

Comment: Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives

Answer (score 1):

I dont really know .Net. But in general a mutex is simplified version of a semaphore:

A semaphore is initialized with a value: Each time a thread accesses a protected resource, the semaphore value will be decremented - until it reaches 0, then no thread can access the resource anymore until one of the threads give up the resource which will increment the value.

A mutex i basically a semaphore with the value 1. So it only allows one thread to access the protected resource and blocks it until the thread leaves the resource.

Look here: http://niclasw.mbnet.fi/MutexSemaphore.html for a great analogy.

Answer (score 0):

> A mutex provides mutual exclusion, either process1 or process2 proceed with 
>     their work. As long as the buffer is filled by process1, the process2 needs to 
>     wait, and vice versa.
>
> A Semaphore restricts the number of concurrent users of a shared resource up to 
>     a maximum number.